# How to split an csv into multiple csv based on calumn value and having first two row as common value?

Tags: csv, file, split

I have a csv with a number value and an alpha value. I want to convert it in multiple files with same numeric value where numeric value can act as name of csv and first two values can be common for all. Any minimal method would be useful (If possible i don't want to install stuff.)The rows in answers are actually columns.
Example
Numeric  Alpha
1 A
1 B
3 C
4 D
4 E
1 F
1 G
2 H
2 I
5 D
6 A
2 A

Result should look like :

1.csv

ID
ex
A
B
F
G

2.csv

ID
ex
H
I
A

3.csv

ID
ex
C

4.csv

ID
ex
D
E

Etc etc.

Comment: your input is on one line?